# Javascript function loading (by reference?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, return-by-reference

While I have many years experience programming (in numerous languages), my background is not Javascript.  Added to that is the fact that the Javascript of today is not the Javascript I first played with many years ago. It's much more sophisticated and powerful.  That said, I'm struggling to understand some function payload dynamics.

Function calls where the function actually returns something are intuitive, but Javascript seems to do something with functions that I can't get my head around.  I could just copy/paste code, or I could try to work out how to reuse this pattern in my own code.

For example, the following Mongoose call does a find of all records in the User model, and somehow the result of the call ends up in the second argument of the passed function (by reference?).

```
User.find({}, function(err, users) {  // Get all the users
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(users); // Show the JSON Object    
});
```

Here's another example using a simple forEach on an array.  Somehow, the forEach populates the 'user' argument.

```
users.forEach(function(user) {
        console.log(user.username, ': Admin = ', (user.admin ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
});
```

Can anyone explain this, and/or point me to a good guide on how/why this works?

I've seen the same pattern across Node.js and it's a bit of a stumbling block.

Have I missed something obvious or is this simply a peculiarity around functional programming?

Jon

Comment: Research `javascript callbacks`.

Comment: Or [Continuation Passing Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) if you want a more general understanding of the technique.

Comment: There's nothing really new with this style. The earliest javascript versions used callbacks as event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments around callbacks.  I do appreciate the time taken to respond.

I thought I was aware of how callbacks work, but I don't see the callback relevance here.  This is not about a function being executed following some other functionality (within the called function), nor is it being used to drive some sequential synchronous processing in context.  I think @naomik has a good point, and I wasn't aware of CPS.

Comment: See comments below.  I can see the callback relevance now.

Comment: CPS / callbacks are just ways that functions are used as arguments. Either way, be very wary of overusing callbacks. If you have the time, learn about using Promises  (as @Dmitriy Nevzorov included). Here's an [article](http://www.luiselizondo.net/synchronous-javascript-using-promises-a-tutorial-on-using-promises/) which shows one of the benefits of Promises over raw callbacks (google "js Promises vs callbacks" for many more examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Continuation Passing Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). It is sometimes used to encapsulate asynchronous behaviours, like the Mongoose example you provided, but other times it can be used in synchronous ways, like the `.forEach` example.

To see how this works, it's easy if we make up our own forEach.

```
function forEach(xs, f)
  for (var i=0, len=xs.length; i<len; i++) {
    f(x[i]);
  }
}

forEach([1,2,3], function(x) { console.log(x); })
```

So the way this works should be pretty easy to see: We can see that `xs` is set to our array `[1,2,3]` where we do a regular `for` loop inside the function. Then we see `f` is called once per element inside the loop.

The real power here is that functions are [first-class members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in JavaScript and this enables the use of [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). This means `.forEach` is considered a higher-order function because it accepts a function as an argument.

As it turns out, `forEach` could be implemented a lot of different ways. here's another.

```
forEach(xs, f) {
  if (xs.length > 0) {
    f(xs[0]);
    forEach(xs.slice(1), f);
  }
}
```

The idea here is you should get comfortable with sending functions around in JavaScript. You can even return functions as the result of applying another function.

```
function add(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

function map(xs, f) {
  function loop(ys, xs) {
    if (xs.length === 0)
      return ys;
    else
      return loop(ys.concat(f(xs[0])), xs.slice(1));
  }
  return loop([], xs);
}

map([1,2,3], add(10)); //=> [11,12,13]
```

Before long, you'll be be knee-deep in the [functional paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and learning all sorts of other new things.

Functions !

Comment: `forEach` doesn't have a lot to do with CPS?

Comment: So the focus on callbacks is confusing.  With the forEach example in my question, user is not a function, it is an object, but it could just as easily be a Number.  CPS is a little enlightening, but the focus on callbacks doesn't help me.

Comment: Right!  I get it, I've been confusing user being assigned a value, with user having a value within the scope of a callback.  The callback is hidden though, so it wasn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, functions are also objects and can be stored in variables. A function that is passed to another function is commonly called a "callback" (this is also used in other languages but we won't go there).

It may be helpful to look at the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) for `Array.prototype.forEach`, especially the line that triggers the callback.

Since, Javascript functions are also objects, they have their own methods, specifically [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which trigger the function and even set the `this` value for that function.

Callback example (it's silly I know... Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2k6voej/)):

```
function callIf(val, callbackFn) {
    // "arguments" is special in javascript, and it's not an array (although it does have an index selector).
    // I can call Array's slice method passing "arguments" as the "this" of the function
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    if(val) {
        callbackFn.apply(this, args);
    }
}

var values = [
    "Hop",
    "on",
    "Pop",
    "Sam",
    "I",
    "Am"
];


values.forEach(function(val) {
    // note: referencing inner "log" function instead of "console.log" because "console.log" require's the "this" to be "console".

    callIf(val.length < 3, log, val + " is a small word.");

    function log(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }
});
```

Side note:

If you're coming from a static type language background, and are encountering Javascript as a dynamically typed language for the first time, my advice to you is: don't worry and embrace the flexibility that Javascript brings, but still maintain consistency and good programming discipline. Emphasize simplicity and readability. Have fun :)

Comment: Thanks - very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need [javascript callbacks](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/javascript-callbacks/)

The basic idea is that you pass one function as an argument to another function and then call it whenever you need it.

```
function basic( callback ){
  console.log( 'do something here' );

  var result = 'i am the result of `do something` to be past to the callback';

  // if callback exist execute it
  callback && callback( result );
}
```

This is one of the core concepts in javascript. But I would recommend you also take a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for async operations like ajax http requests. Its not a part of current `ES5` specification but you can find many libraries and polyfils for this.

```
function get(url) {
  // Return a new promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      // This is called even on 404 etc
      // so check the status
      if (req.status == 200) {
        // Resolve the promise with the response text
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        // Otherwise reject with the status text
        // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // Make the request
    req.send();
  });
}

// Use it!
get('story.json').then(function(response) {
  console.log("Success!", response);
}, function(error) {
  console.error("Failed!", error);
});
```

Comment: Even promises use callbacks, so you should understand the concept of callbacks in general at first anyway.

Comment: Thanks - also very useful

Answer (score 1):

Those callbacks look similar but they serves completely different purposes. In the first example, the callback is used for retrieving the result because `User.find` is an asynchronous function. Async nature is also the reason behind the Nodejs convention of callback arguments order. First arguments of callbacks are always for errors.

In the second example, the primary reason for using callback is to create a local scope, which is quite useful when you want to execute some asynchronous operations within the loop. For example:

```
users.forEach(function(user) {
    Model.find({},function(er,rows){
        if(er){
            return handle(er);
        }
        OtherModel.find({userid: user.id},function(er,result){
            if(er){
                return handle(er);
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
});
```

The above example migth not work with the C-style loop since variables defined with `var` will already be overwrited by the last item of the array when `OtherModle.find` is executed.